# phpUnit config options

Tags: php, configuration, yui, phpunit

what do the following options mean or whats it for

```
<log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
    lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
```

- yui: i guess it means use stuff from yahoo ui to make it look good?
- highlight: maybe have some colors?
- lowUpperBound, highLowerbound: whats these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lowUpperBound` = your idea till which percentage code should be covered to be regarded as low.
By default everything below 35 is low. You specified everything below 50 as low meaning your tests will be harder to get out of the red.

`highUpperBound` = the same as lowUpperBound but for the minimum percentage the coverage should have before you regard it as high coverage. By default it is 70. So again you made your code statistically more difficult to qualify.

More information is available [in the manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging).

Answer (score 1):

As of the 3.7 release (taken from [the manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html)):

> **highlight**: When set to `true`, the code in your coverage reports is syntax highlighted.
>
> **lowUpperBound**: Maximum coverage percentage to be considered "lowly" covered.
>
> **highLowerBound**: Minimum coverage percentage to be considered "highly" covered.

`yui` is an **outdated** option and no longer does anything. The most recent release I can find with it still present is [3.6](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html):

> **yui**: Enhance html coverage report using the yui library. For example, when you click a line number, a YUI panel appears with a list of all methods which cover that line.